# C Sockets Client/Server pthreads server broadcast

Tags: c, sockets, server, pthreads, client

We were given this code, and was supposed to modify it so that whenever a client connects to a server and sends a message the server should reply I hear you dude. That is working for one and multiple clients but next task was to when ever a new client connects the server should tell that to all the other clients that are connected.

I assumed this would be fairly easy but its not working out like I thought it would. Since the server always get sock 3 and first client gets 4 and second client gets 5 etc, I tried to make a for loop that messaged whenever a new client connects the loop will send message to 4,5 which just made the server close itself directly. I then tried to just make when ever a new client connects that the server should message the first client(4) which it actually does but only if client(4) writes a message to the server he recieves that broadcast that the server sent.

So it seems like the client wants to write but needs to write something before he recieves the broadcast from the server, any help would appreciated since we're kinda beginners with all this.

This is how the code looks like at the moment.

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 5555
#define MAXMSG 512


void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message, client_message[2000], *message_to_client;
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));
    while( (read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
    {
       client_message[read_size] = '\0';
       printf("Client[%d]: %s", sock, client_message);
       message_to_client = "I hear you dude...";
       write(sock, message_to_client, 19);
       memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
       printf("Client[%d] disconnected", sock);
       fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
       perror("recv failed");

    }
    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}

int makeSocket(unsigned short int port) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in name;
    /* Create a socket. */
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0) {
        perror("Could not create a socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_port = htons(port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&name, sizeof(name)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not bind a name to the socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return(sock);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    int clientSocket;
    int i;
    int *new_sock;
    char *broadcast;
    fd_set activeFdSet, readFdSet;
    struct sockaddr_in clientName;
    socklen_t size;
    sock = makeSocket(PORT);
    if(listen(sock,1) < 0) 
    {
        perror("Could not listen for connections\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FD_ZERO(&activeFdSet);
    FD_SET(sock, &activeFdSet);
    while(1) 
    {
        printf("Waiting for connections\n");
        readFdSet = activeFdSet;
        if(select(FD_SETSIZE, &readFdSet, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror("Select failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &readFdSet)) 
            {
                if(i == sock) 
                {
                    size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                    pthread_t sniffer_thread;
                    while(( clientSocket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&clientName, (socklen_t *)&size))) 
                    {
                        puts("Connection accepted");
                        new_sock = malloc(1);
                        *new_sock = clientSocket;
                        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler, (void*) new_sock) < 0)
                        {
                            perror("could not create thread");
                            return 1;
                        }
                        broadcast = "NEW CLIENT CONNECTED";
                        write(4, broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)); //just to see if when ever a new client connects the first client should get all these messages
                        write(4, broadcast, sizeof(broadcast));
                        write(4, broadcast, sizeof(broadcast));
                        pthread_detach(sniffer_thread);
                        puts("Handler assigned");
                        FD_SET(*new_sock, &activeFdSet);

                   }
                   if(clientSocket < 0) 
                   {
                       perror("Could not accept connection\n");
                       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                   }                
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(readMessageFromClient(i) < 0)
                    {
                    close(i);
                        FD_CLR(i, &activeFdSet);
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

and for the client the code looks like this

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 5555
#define hostNameLength 50
#define messageLength  256

void initSocketAddress(struct sockaddr_in *name, char *hostName, unsigned short int port) 
{
  struct hostent *hostInfo; 
  name->sin_family = AF_INET;
  name->sin_port = htons(port);
  hostInfo = gethostbyname(hostName);
  if(hostInfo == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "initSocketAddress - Unknown host %s\n",hostName);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  name->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *)hostInfo->h_addr;
}
void writeMessage(int fileDescriptor, char *message) 
{
  int nOfBytes;
  nOfBytes = write(fileDescriptor, message, strlen(message) + 1);
  if(nOfBytes < 0) 
  {
    perror("writeMessage - Could not write data\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in serverName;
  char hostName[hostNameLength];
  char messageString[messageLength];
  char buffer[1024];
  if(argv[1] == NULL) 
  {
    perror("Usage: client [host name]\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else 
  {
    strncpy(hostName, argv[1], hostNameLength);
    hostName[hostNameLength - 1] = '\0';
  }

  sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sock < 0) 
  {
    perror("Could not create a socket\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  initSocketAddress(&serverName, hostName, PORT);
  if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serverName, sizeof(serverName)) < 0) 
  {
    perror("Could not connect to server\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("\nType something and press [RETURN] to send it to the server.\n");
  printf("Type 'quit' to nuke this program.\n");
  fflush(stdin);
  recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
  printf(buffer);
  while(1) 
  {
    printf("\n>");
      fgets(messageString, messageLength, stdin);
      messageString[messageLength - 1] = '\0';
      if(strncmp(messageString, "quit\n",messageLength) != 0)
         writeMessage(sock, messageString);
      if(recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0) > 0)
               printf(buffer);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make couple of changes to your code to get it working. Reason you are not receiving anything is your client is stuck at

fgets(messageString, messageLength, stdin); which is a blocking call , so just create a thread for message receiving at client end so that it can listen continuously. Make below changes to code and it should help you to achieve your results.

Add below lines to client end of code:

client.c

```
void * receiveMessage(void * socket)
{
    int sockfd, ret;
    char buffer[1024];
    sockfd = (int) socket;
    int count = 1;
     memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
     for (;;)
     {
         if (recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) > 0)
         {
             fputs(buffer, stdout);
             printf("\n");
         }
     }
}
```

in main function add below lines

```
 //creating a new thread for receiving messages from the server
   read = pthread_create(&rThread, NULL, receiveMessage, (void *) sock);
   if (read < 0)
   {
       printf("ERROR: Return Code from pthread_create() is %d\n", read);
       exit(1);
   }
```

and change while loop to below

```
 while(1)
  {
      printf("\n>");

      fgets(messageString, messageLength, stdin);

      messageString[messageLength - 1] = '\0';

      if(strncmp(messageString, "quit\n",messageLength) != 0)
      {
          writeMessage(sock, messageString);
      }
  }
```

Server.c  ( Add broadcast message in connection handler )

```
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message, client_message[2000], *message_to_client;
    char broadcast[50] = "new client connected";
    int num;

    num = sock;
    num--;
    while(num > 3)
    {
        write(num, broadcast, strlen(broadcast));
        sleep(1);
        num--;
    }

    while((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
    {
       client_message[read_size] = '\0';
       printf("Client[%d]: %s", sock, client_message);
       message_to_client = "I hear you dude...";
       write(sock, message_to_client, strlen(message_to_client));
       memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        printf("Client[%d] disconnected", sock);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");

    }

    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is almost how we made it to work, had forgotten to put the while loop for the client to read.